What is the main cause of pressure recovery on airfoil?
What is the main cause of pressure recovery over a wing? I’ve narrowed it down to be one of or a combination of 2 things:

The higher pressure air from the bottom of the wing equalizing with the upper surface pressure, explained here clearly.
The atmospheric air pressure equalizing with the air pressure on top of the wing.

So is it both of these that cause pressure recovery? Does one contribute more than the other?
(If I had to guess, it probably depends on the scenario, high AoA, maneuvering, etc)
(It’s also possible there’s another cause I missed and don’t know about)

I don't love your wording, but it is essentially your bullet two.  But your bullet one is also true.
Although the pressure can increase / decrease when the flow accelerates around the body, it must eventually return to the ambient pressure.  At the trailing edge, the top/bottom pressure must be equal.
For subsonic airfoils, you essentially reach ambient pressure  at the trailing edge.  You can be a bit off, but you're pretty close at the TE.

I see. So for supersonic airfoils the pressure isn’t at ambient when you get to the TE? (I know for subsonic airfoils it isn’t either, but subsonic airfoils are closer to ambient)

The TE shocks on a supersonic airfoil satisfy the condition that the upper and lower pressures are equal and the TE velocities are parallel.
